# iPad: What happens to iAds if iOS on user's machine doesn't support them?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios

Ok,

So say I put some iAds in my iPad app. Assuming that I implement it via the iOS4.2 update that comes out next week.

Now, say I release my product but the majority of users haven't installed iOS4.2 in their iPads yet. Does that mean that my app will not run on their systems (meaning, my app *requires* iOS4.2), or does it mean that it'll run in their system (say iOS 3.2.2) but just the iAds won't show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding making your app available on iOS 3.2 devices: Make sure to *weak link* iAd.framework (i.e. in your target's settings, choose 'Weak Link' next to iAd.framework) as it is not available on iOS 3.2. You should also check for availability like

```
if (NULL != NSClassFromString(@"ADBannerView"))
{
    // handle ad loading here
}
else
{
    // no iAds available.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends how you compiled your app.

- You can specify that an app can run on iOS 3.2.2, but can still use features of iOS 4.2, by carefully checking the availability before using these features.
- You can also specify that your app can only run on iOS 4.2 and later; then you can use iOS 4.2 features without checking the availability.

So, it's your choice. Read [this Apple document.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000163-BCICHGIE)